# Could there exist gauge-symmetry-protected topological order?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, gauge-theory, topological-order, topological-phase

More precisely, let $\hat{H}_1, \hat{H}_2$ be  locally-interacting, translation-invariant quantum many-body Hamiltonians (defined on the same quantum system) that both has a gauge symmetry $G$, and their repective ground states $|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle$ are both gapped and non-degenerate, and are both invariant under $G$. We say that $|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle$ represent distinct topological phases protected by gauge symmetry $G$ if the following two statements are true:

(1) There exists interpolating Hamiltonian $H(\lambda)$  with $H(0)=H_1, H(1)=H_2$, and $H(\lambda)$ is locally-interacting, translation invariant, and gapped for all $\lambda\in[0 ,1]$;

(2) Any $H(\lambda)$ satisfying (1) must break the gauge symmetry $G$ for some $\lambda\in(0,1)$.

Is gauge-symmetry-protected topological order possible or not?

Comment: You can have SPTs for higher symmetries, such as the center symmetry of a pure G gauge theory or the magnetic symmetry in the absence of monopoles. In some formulations, these symmetries are baked in to the Hilbert space. Beyond that, the gauge symmetry is not really physical.